# How to put looping array to array store data in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have array from my database and I loop with foreach in Codeigniter Controller

My code like this :

```
$day_total  =31;
$no=1;
foreach ($attendance_2->result_array() as $attend_list) {
            foreach ($rows2 as $i){
                if ($i = $attend_list['sn']) {

                    $a = $attend_list['name'];
                    $b = $attend_list['pst_desc'];
                    $d = array();
                    for($m=1; $m <= $day_total; $m++){
                        $d[]=$m;
                    }
                }
            }
            $data[] = array (
                $no++,
                $a,
                $b,
                $d
            );
        }

            $output = array(
                "draw"              => $draw,
                "recordsTotal"      => $attendance_2->num_rows(),
                "recordsFiltered"   => $attendance_2->num_rows(),
                "data"              => $data
            );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

I want to array $d put on store Data[] and looks like below

```
$data[] = array (
$no++,
$a,
$b,
$d[0],
$d[1],
$d[2],
etc
);
```

how to do it?

Comment: Where is `$no++` and `$day_total` in your code?

Comment: i have edit my code. Please see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get straight array then you need to used [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

So change this line

```
$data[] = array (
                $no++,
                $a,
                $b,
                $d
            );
```

To

```
$temp = array($no++,
                $a,
                $b);
$data[] = array_merge($temp,$d);
```

You also need to check empty condition for `$a`, `$b` and `$d`. As in your code, I can see you are getting all values in `if condition`, So there is no `else condition` for getting values.

Comment: thanks @hardik solanki, it's worked. thank you for sugestion, i will check it.

Comment: Glad to help you.